# str_replace() with foreach, uppercase and exact word matching

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, str-replace

My code is:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('old', 'new')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__words'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadAssocList();
$find = array();
$replace = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
 $find[] = $row['old'];
 $replace[] = $row['new'];
}
$newstring = str_replace($find, $replace, $oldstring);
echo $newstring;
```

This code replaces all the words from the "old" column with the words from the column "new". But there are two problems. First it works if the found and replaced words both have the same case (upper or lower), but I need it would be working regardless of the case i.e. the DB has only in lowercase but if the finding word on the front-end have uppercase, the replaced word must have uppercase too. Secondly, I need exact word matching. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then try [str_ireplace](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the finding word on the front-end [has] uppercase"? If only the first letter of a word is uppercase, does the first letter of the replacement string be uppercase too? Or words are always entirely uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: All possible cases is the best solution i.e. replaced word must be always in the same case as the found one (old - new, Old - New, OLD - NEW) but in the DB they must be in lowercase only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$oldstring = 'The cat and the dog are flying into the kitchen. Dog. Cat. DOG. CAT';

$results = array( array('old'=>'cat', 'new'=>'chat'), array('old'=>'dog', 'new'=>'chien'));
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $fndrep[$row['old']] = $row['new'];
}

$pattern = '~(?=([A-Z]?)([a-z]?))\b(?i)(?:'
 // cyrillic => '~(?=([\x{0410}-\x{042F}]?)([\x{0430}-\x{044F}]?))\b(?i)(?:'
         . implode('|', array_keys($fndrep))
         . ')\b~';  // cyrillic => ')\b~u';

$newstring = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($fndrep) {
    $lowm = $fndrep[strtolower($m[0])];
    if ($m[1])
        return ($m[2]) ? ucfirst($lowm) : strtoupper($lowm);
    else
        return $lowm;
}, $oldstring);

echo $newstring;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes working, but with english only. I need for cyrillic, sorry I didn't mentioned about it in the post

Comment: @jumlancer: you only need to replace the range `A-Z` with cyrillic uppercase letters and `a-z` with lowercase.